# Check value select option list

Tags: jquery

I´ve got a wordpress plugin that generates an option list. The generated code is like this:

```
<select name="question">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="maybe">Maybe</option></select>

<p id="text">some text</p>
```

Underneath is a paragraph i like to show if the option maybe is selected. If Yes or No is selected this should be hidden.

The Jquery script i came up with (after lot's of googling, copying and pasting) is this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var selectVal = $(‘select’).val();

            if( $selectVal=="maybe"){
              $('#text').show();}
            else{
            $('#text').hide();}
        });
```

Unfortunally this doesn't work. Anybody has an idea what i'm doing wrong or how to do it right?

Comment: According to the change event docs: `For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus`

Comment: What exactly do you mean "doesn't work"? What does it do, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name=question]').change(function(){
  var selectVal = $(this).val();

  if( selectVal=="maybe"){
     $('#text').show();
  }else{
     $('#text').hide();}
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/xqCKD/

Answer (score 2):

`$selectVal` is different from `selectVal`. And smart quotes are a no-no in jQuery selectors.

You also need to hide the paragraph onload. CSS `display: none` can do this best.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/uz2uf/

Incidentally, you can pass a Boolean to the `.toggle()` method to shorten up your code:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    $('#text').toggle(selectVal=="maybe");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/uz2uf/1/

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger. It's a nice solution and works perfect in jsfiddle. Only together with my wordpress plugin it didn't work. I've changed the toggle function to the if and else of Shortround1911 and now it does work. :)

Comment: Passing a Boolean to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) was added in jQuery 1.3 -- I wonder if WordPress is actually running a version that old.